# iOS Location Services Fail when testing in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I am trying to use a GPX file to test location services on an app while running the app on iOS Simulator on my Mac. I have added the GPX file to my Mac, and the Navigation icon in the *Debug* toolbar turns blue.

However, when I decide to run my app, the icon on the Debug bar turns grey and the app cannot find my location. This problem exists when I use another location (London, which is built in and not a GPX file) also.

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Comment: Probably you are using a wrong GPX file (wrong formatting I mean). Could you put the content of the file here?

Comment: thanks for your help! here it is,<gpx>
    <wpt lat="41.504341" lon="-81.608384"></wpt>
</gpx>

Comment: Sorry don't know the answer. but another direction you could try is see whether location service is turned on for the device. The GPX file looks fine.